# Type error in expression ($7479f9280145788e8229._) in multi-project sbt build

Tags: jenkins, sbt

I have a multi-project sbt build that fails. The tail end of the jenkins log is below.
The arbitrary name of the import suggests generated code but I don't understand how to start debugging this.

```
[debug] Initial source changes: 
[debug]     removed:Set()
[debug]     added: Set()
[debug]     modified: Set()
[debug] Removed products: Set()
[debug] External API changes: API Changes: Set()
[debug] Modified binary dependencies: Set()
[debug] Initial directly invalidated sources: Set()
[debug] 
[debug] Sources indirectly invalidated by:
[debug]     product: Set()
[debug]     binary dep: Set()
[debug]     external source: Set()
[debug] All initially invalidated sources: Set()
[debug] Copy resource mappings: 
[debug]     
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/web-release-sbt/workspace/TrailHunger2/apiServer/build.sbt:0: error: not found: object $7479f9280145788e8229
import $7479f9280145788e8229._
       ^
[error] Type error in expression
[debug] > load-failed
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? Build     step 'Build using sbt' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Build using sbt' marked build as failure
Pushing tag jenkins-web-release-sbt-31 to repo origin
Finished: FAILURE
```